# How do I implement muiltiple/combined/composed generation strategies in jooq?

Tags: jooq

I have:

```
                    .withStrategy(Strategy().apply {
                        name = "rcp.RenamingStrategy"
                        matchers = Matchers().withTables(MatchersTableType().apply {
                            tableImplements = "rcp.framework.db.EntityTable"
                            pojoImplements = "rcp.framework.db.Entity"
                            recordImplements = "rcp.framework.db.Record"
                            interfaceImplements = "rcp.framework.db.DbInterface"
                        })
                    })
```

This doesn't work; only either one of the named strategy or the matchers apply (with both uncommented, the matchers takes precedence). It also doesn't work to have two .withStrategy clauses, separating them out.

I did find `getJavaClassImplements(definition: Definition?, mode: Mode?): MutableList<String>` in DefaultGeneratorStrategy, but Mode appears to be incomplete - there's no "table" mode. Tables get passed through with DEFAULT, but so do enums and various other misc objects.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do with a single strategy? The goal is to make a dao implementation for basic common functions that includes business logic that jooq's dao generation does not, and for that I need interfaces around the various types of objects that I control.

Comment: What does `RenamingStrategy` do? Does the matcher strategy's regex support not suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you cannot combine the two types of strategy. It's difficult to see how such a combination should work, given that a `GeneratorStrategy` is an interface with mandatory implementations (typically from the default implementation) and without any precedence.

> but Mode appears to be incomplete - there's no "table" mode. Tables get passed through with DEFAULT, but so do enums and various other misc objects.

`Mode` just tells you in what "mode" the generation is for a certain `Definition` type. E.g. for `TableDefinition`, there is:

- `DEFAULT`: The `Table` object
- `RECORD`: The `TableRecord` object
- `DAO`: `The` DAO` object
- etc.

So, you have to implement a `definition is TableDefinition` check to apply a strategy only to tables.